# Bitrix. Как настроить события и шаблоны письма по типу плательщика

Tags: битрикс, события, настройка

уважаемые стековерфлоисты!=)

Вопрос больше для битриксоидов.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне можно настроить события на отправку определенных писем по типу плательщика?
У нас идет разделение оформления заказа на физические(оформляют за себя) и юридические лица(оформляют данные по своей компании и за человека, который к ним обратился)
[image: Пример формы для юр лица]

События отлавливают создание нового заказа и направляют нам на почту с заполненными данными, как и покупателям. Но под общий шаблон их не загонишь (Для физич. - адрес доставки, фио, почта и сам заказ. Для юридических - реквизиты компании, представитель компании, юридический адрес, фио клиента, почта клиента и телефон клиента со списком товаров. ).

По битрикс:
1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 20.0.0. © Битрикс, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать соответствующие отдельные шаблоны. Затем создать обработчик события [`OnBeforeEventSend`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onbeforeeventsend.php)
И в обработчике в зависимости от нужных вам условий подменять шаблон по которому отправлять сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно в шаблоне написать приблизительно такое

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Реквизит</td><td>Значение</td></tr>
#ORDER_PROP_VALUE#
</tbody>
</table>
```

И на обработчику OnBeforeEventAdd

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnBeforeEventAdd", array("MyClass", "OnBeforeEventAddHandler"));
class MyClass
{
    function OnBeforeEventAddHandler(&$event, &$lid, &$arFields)
    {
       $prop = self::GetOrderProp(); // нужно описать
       
       foreach ($prop as $itemProp){
         ob_start();
         ?>
         <tr>
           <td>
               <?=$itemProp["NAME"]?>
           </td>
           <td>
               <?=$itemProp["VALUE"]?>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <?
    
         $arFields["ORDER_PROP_VALUE"] .= ob_get_clean();
      }
   }
}
```